# Disable Firefox sponsored results

Tags: firefox, browser, search, about-config

To my horror, I just noticed today that Firefox injects sponsored results into
any search:

> [image: sponsor]

I want this gone now. Is it possible to disable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be controlled by this setting:

```
browser.newtabpage.activity-stream.showSponsoredTopSites
```

changing to `false` in about:config appears to have fixed the problem.

https://ghacks.net/2020/11/22/how-to-disable-sponsored-top-sites-in-the-firefox-web-browser

Answer (score 5):

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/sponsor-privacy

That should do it

> [image: sponsor]

"In the Firefox Home Content section, unselect Sponsored shortcuts."